# newbie cross-correlation in matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I'm trying to understand how the cross correlation in matlab, mainly xcorr, works. This an example code:

```
t = -4*pi:0.1:4*pi;
y1 = sin(t*pi);
y2 = sin(t*pi - 0.7*pi);
[acor,lag] = xcorr(y1,y2,50);
[~,I] = max(abs(acor));
lagDiff = lag(I)
```

and the answer is:

```
  3
```

Now you multiply the the delta t by 3 so you get (0.1*3) and the time lag is 0.3, while the  true answer is 0.7*3.14 which is roughly 2.2 I cant figure out what I'm doing wrong

thanks in advance

Comment: Why is t defined as `t = -4*pi:0.1:4*pi;`? And then you multiplying by `pi` again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two things wrong:

1. You should not use `abs` in the maximization.
2. `0.7*3.14` is the true *phase* lag, not the true *time* lag. The true time lag is `-0.7` (note also the minus sign).

Let me elaborate these two points.

1. You need to use

   ```
   [~,I] = max(acor)
   ```

   that is, remove `abs`. Using `abs` you may be finding the lag at which the signals give a very large *negative* correlation, which is not what you want.

   With this modification, you get `I=44` and `lagDiff=-7`.

   Now, according to your definition of `t`, your sampling period is `0.1`. So the result `lagDiff=-7` (in samples) corresponds to `-0.7` seconds.
2. Your reasoning about the true answer is not correct. The true answer is not `0.7*3.14`, but `-0.7`. To see why, note that your definition

   ```
   y2 = sin(t*pi - 0.7*pi);
   ```

   is equivalent to

   ```
   y2 = sin((t-0.7)*pi);
   ```

   Comparing with

   ```
   y1 = sin(t*pi);
   ```

   it's clear that `y2` is `y1` with time advanced by `0.7` seconds; or delayed by `-0.7` seconds.

In conclusion, the result given by the code without `abs` is in accordance with the true answer: `-0.7` seconds.